# Android setting TextView text without declaring variable

Tags: java, android, textview

I normally set a TextView's text this way:

```
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbC1Voice);
        tv.setText("ss");
```

Isn't there a way to set it without declaring tv? e.g.

```
(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbC1Voice).setText("ss");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the return value of `findViewById()`, not `findViewById(...).setText()`.
Use parentheses to specify the scope of the cast:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbC1Voice)).setText("ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbC1Voice).setText("ss");
```

to

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbC1Voice)).setText("ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbC1Voice)).setText("ss");
```